# Elastic search Nest C# - Is it possible a case insensitive sort on a string field through automap

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a elasticsearch Nest Model class

```
public class Data
    {       
        public long Id { get; set; }
       
        public string DeviceCode { get; set; }
    }
```

When indexing this document using automap , nest will create two fields for the property DeviceCode - DeviceCode and DeviceCode.keyword. I want to sort based on the DeviceCode.keyword field with case insensitive sorting - Is it possible to acheive this through automap (by applying analyser or filter using  attribute mapping in the model class). I want to keep both text and keyword fields in elastic search.

Regards
Vineeth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to apply a [normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html) to a `keyword` field to lowercase values at index time for case-insensitive querying and aggregations

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
    
var createIndexResponse = client.Indices.Create("my-data", c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .Normalizers(n => n
                .Custom("lowercase", cn => cn
                    .Filters("lowercase")
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .Map<Data>(m => m
        .AutoMap()
        .Properties(p => p
            .Text(t => t
                .Name(n => n.DeviceCode)
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Keyword(k => k
                        .Name("keyword")
                        .IgnoreAbove(256)
                    )
                    .Keyword(k => k
                        .Name("keyword_lowercase")
                        .Normalizer("lowercase")
                        .IgnoreAbove(256)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Then to use the `keyword_lowercase` [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/multi-fields.html)

```cs
var searchResponse = client.Search<Data>(s => s
    .Index("my-data")
    .Sort(so => so
        .Ascending(f => f.DeviceCode.Suffix("keyword_lowercase"))
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you @Russ. I have used the similar settings to acheive this.  Can you please clarify whether we can use attributes to acheive this in Nest to avoid the explicit property mappings while indexing. Eg:  [Keyword(Normalizer = "lowercase")]
                                public string ClientCode { get; set; }      This will create a keyword field and keyword field only while indexing using AutoMap. Is there any way to store this field as both text and keyword field using attributes mapping.

Comment: No, it's not possible to configure a multi-field with attribute mapping, only with fluent mapping

Comment: Ok. Thank you Russ for the clarification.